# Switch which stylesheet is imported based on variable like %PUBLIC_URL%

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap in my react app and have added

`<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to my index.html.

What I want to do is switch which stylesheet I'm using based on a variable like `%PUBLIC_URL%`.

Concretely what I want is

`<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/%STYLESHEET_NAME%" rel="stylesheet">`

And a place to specify `%STYLESHEET_NAME%`

Comment: Which template engine do you use?

Comment: I'm not using a template engine, this is webpack's variable I believe